# babel build missing requires

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have just upgraded to babel `v7` and `building` my project I saw that it was only building my `index.js` and not any imports used in that file.

I would like the build to include all imports so that I can use my built file.

## .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

## index.js

```
import FetchApi from './utils/fetch'

export const aFunc = function () {FetchApi()}    
export default aFunc
```

## build.js

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = exports.aFunc = void 0;

var _fetch = _interopRequireDefault(require("./utils/fetch"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

const aFunc = function () {
  (0, _fetch.default)();
};

exports.aFunc = aFunc;
var _default = aFunc;
exports.default = _default;
```

The line in question is here:    `var _fetch = _interopRequireDefault(require("./utils/fetch"));`

Comment: what command are you using to run `babel`?

Comment: Good point: `babel ./index.js -d build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`babel <src-file>` will only transpile a single source file.  you can [transpile all source files in a directory](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-directories) by specifying a directory instead of a single source file: `babel <src-dir> -d build`.  this will produce a tree of transpiled files, and your require statements will resolve to transpiled modules.

if you're looking to combine all of your source files into a single output file, there's also babel's `--out-file` flag but it might not do what you want (it just `cat`s all transpiled files into a single output file; your require statements will still exist, will still point to external files, and will fail at runtime).  you might need a bundler like webpack/rollup/parcel to turn require statements into inline modules, allowing you to generate a single, self-contained, transpiled build artifact.